# check if integer is inputted in java and not string

Tags: java, string, input, integer

I have a code below wherein a user must input numbers only, the program is working but the problem is the System.out.println("Mother's Age: ") is being printed 2 times during loading

```
    while (count == 0){
        int x;
        System.out.println("Mother's Age: ");
        ans2 = input.nextLine();
        try{
            x = Integer.parseInt(ans2);
            System.out.println(count);                
            if (!(x >= 18 && x <= 45)) {
            }
            else{
                count = 1;
            }
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException nFE){
        }
    }
```

Comment: Move it outside of the `while` loop, preferably before...

Comment: I need to asked again that question for the user to be able to put another answer so I made a loop

Comment: what is the type of variable 'input'?

Comment: Then something's wrong with your code that's not shown here.

Comment: @sidgate looks like a `Scanner`. It doesn't matter to find the real problem.

Comment: Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

Comment: Why don't you use `if(input.hasNextInt())` to know if user is inputting a number instead of a `try-catch` block?

Comment: I doubt that input.nextLine is getting some value for the first time, throws an exception then comes back. Should print the stacktrace in the catch block to confirm

Comment: Have you at least debugged this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
System.out.println("Mother's Age: ");
while (count == 0){
        int x;
        ans2 = input.nextLine();
        try{
            x = Integer.parseInt(ans2);
            System.out.println(count);                
            if (!(x >= 18 && x <= 45)) {
            }
            else{
                count = 1;
            }
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException nFE){
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `System.out.println("Mother's Age: ");` after or before while loop( `Outside loop`).

because it is going in **else condition** second time.

Comment: If the code goes through the `else` condition, it won't print the message again...

Comment: yeah same thing I want to tell.

Comment: Looks like OP was trolling us or he/she doesn't really understand about programming (see the accepted answer)...

Answer (score 0):

It's been printed twice, because of user's input, try to put a message into de if cause like this:

```
 while (count == 0){
    int x;
    System.out.println("Mother's Age: ");
    ans2 = input.nextLine();
    try{
        x = Integer.parseInt(ans2);
        System.out.println(count);                
        if (!(x >= 18 && x <= 45)) {
             System.out.println("Invalid age!!!");
        }
        else{
            count = 1;
        }
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException nFE){
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got this from your help and its working on what Im expecting, thank you!

```
   System.out.println("Mother's Age At Conception(18-45): ");
    while (count == 0){
        int x;
        ans2 = input.nextLine();
        try{
            x = Integer.parseInt(ans2);           
            if (!(x >= 18 && x <= 45)) {
                System.out.println("Invalid Input Please Try Again!");
                System.out.println("Mother's Age At Conception(18-45): ");
            }
            else{
                count = 1;
            }
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException nFE){
        }
    }
```